# How to create new closure cell objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, closures, monkeypatching

I need to monkey-patch my library to replace an instance of a symbol, and it's getting referenced by some function closures. I need to copy those functions (since I also need access to original unpatched version of the function as well), but `__closure__` is immutable, and I can't `copy.copy` it, so how can I create new closure cells objects in Python 2.7?

I for example given this function

```
def f():
    def incorrectfunction():
        return 0
    def g():
        return incorrectfunction()
    return g

def correctfunction():
    return 42

func = f()
patched_func = patchit(f)   # replace "incorrectfunction"
print func(), patched_func()
```

And I want to see

```
0, 42
```

Comment: Is `functools.partial(f, 2)()` good enough?

Comment: No, because I'm using it for monkey-patching. IE, I need to run "patchit" function over all the symbols to replace the old symbol contained in closures with the monkey-patched symbol

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, replaced my toy example with a more realistic version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple way to make a closure cell would be to make a closure:

```
def make_cell(val=None):
    x = val
    def closure():
        return x
    return closure.__closure__[0]
```

If you want to reassign an existing cell's contents, you'll need to make a [C API](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/cell.html) call:

```
import ctypes
PyCell_Set = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCell_Set

# ctypes.pythonapi functions need to have argtypes and restype set manually
PyCell_Set.argtypes = (ctypes.py_object, ctypes.py_object)

# restype actually defaults to c_int here, but we might as well be explicit
PyCell_Set.restype = ctypes.c_int

PyCell_Set(cell, new_value)
```

CPython only, of course.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: If you just need to copy a closure cell, that's easy just by making a closure.

Comment: You can make a writable cell by making the closure inside a generator that stores `send` values into the local variable closed over.

Comment: @DavisHerring: I was thinking more of reassigning an existing cell's contents, not a cell you control the creation of. If you control the creation, then that works. (It's easier on Python 3, where you can just use `nonlocal`, but this question was asked for Python 2.7.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276834/how-to-set-the-content-of-a-closure-cell/59276835#59276835 for a way to set an existing cell's content in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

in lambda:

```
def make_cell(value):
    fn = (lambda x: lambda: x)(value)
    return fn.__closure__[0]
```

got anwer from https://github.com/nedbat/byterun/blob/master/byterun/pyobj.py#L12

Answer (score 0):

If you want an empty cell (which is what I found this question for) (One where referencing it raises a `NameError: free variable '...' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope` and accessing it's `cell.cell_contents` raises a `ValueError: Cell is empty`), you can make a value a local variable, but never let it be assigned:

```
def make_empty_cell():
    if False:
        # Any action that makes `value` local to `make_empty_cell`
        del value
    return (lambda: value).__closure__[0]
```

You can combine them like this:

```
_SENTINEL = object()

def make_cell(value=_SENTINEL):
    if value is not _SENTINEL:
        x = value
    return (lambda: x).__closure__[0]
```

So calling with no arguments returns an empty cell, and with any value, a cell with that value.

If you don't care about empty cells, you can do:

```
def make_cell(value):
    return (lambda: value).__closure__[0]
```

Note that it is `func_closure` in older Python 2, instead of `__closure__`.